# multipe profiles on marshmallow: how to use apps in both accounts

Tags: applications, 6.0-marshmallow, installation, multi-user

i have a tablet with android marshmellow and primary and secondary profile. Appararently apart from the standard apps i can not install apps paralell on the first and the second profile.if i install vlc for example on profile one i can't install it on profile two. it just says "app not installed". Same goes for apps installed on profile two but not installed on profile one . if i try to install them on profile one: "app not installed". We don't use google accounts and i don't want to use google play. Try to use mainly fdroid and aurora\yalp. even tried installing vlc per .apk but also no success. Is there any solution without rooting device, using google accounts, using google play, using adb, custom roms and updating android. Best, bogotrax

Answer (score 1):

I made a second profile myself to test if I'd encounter the same problem, which I did, and after googling a bit it seems the problem is caused if profile X does not install the exact same app version as profile Y. See [this Reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/GrapheneOS/comments/c5szco/on_new_user_profile_cant_install_fdroid/). As such it seems cross-profile app installation is best achieved by [extracting .apk files](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/axp.tool.apkextractor/), copying them to the other profile, and installing them there to make sure you have the same versions.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot - I'll test that.